# Appname having dots at last of appname

Tags: ios, application-name

I am having application name as "MYApplication" but it showing me as "MYApplica..." below app icon in mobile.

Now i want to show that fullname as application name, please give me any solution to fix this issue

Note : I have already set appname as "MYApplication" in info.plist (Bundle name)

Thank you.

Comment: That means the names too long to show the full name in that context.

Comment: then what is the solution if we want to show that full name ?

Comment: I doubt there is one. Any app with a name that long will likely be truncated as well. Use a shorter name if you want it all to show.

Comment: Even the stack exchange app has this "problem": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222335/use-shorter-home-screen-app-title-so-that-it-doesnt-get-truncated

Comment: ohwww...i see... that means i have to give shorter name if i wanna show it full.... am i right...?

Comment: Yes. Or convince Apple to change how many characters they allow to be shown. I can see just changing your name to be easier though.

Comment: @BhaumikJoshi, you can either choose a shorter name or live with the truncated name; there is no other solution available at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an iOS limitation; not anything that you can control. Even the [SE app is effected by this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222335/use-shorter-home-screen-app-title-so-that-it-doesnt-get-truncated).

Just use a shorter name if you don't want it to be cut off.

The exact cut off point will likely depend on the resolution of the screen it's being displayed on though. If you're worried about how your app name will appear when cut off, you may want to play around with an emulator or something to see how it displays on different devices.

I seem to recall it being possible to effect how many characters are shown if your iPhone is jailbroken, but that only effects your phone obviously, not the phones of people who use your app.

Comment: And to add to this correct answer, be sure to check the display of the name on different devices, iPhones, iPads, older devices, different version of iOS, etc. They are not all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your app name is getting truncate trail.

You can keep max 13 or 14 characters only. Depending on character width. “I” takes less width while “B” makes much width. So think about appropriate name of app and set it. In iOS we can not keep 2 line app name like Android device has option.